# Cognito SSO login with Ionic Capacitor not working in Android/IOS in Amplify

Tags: ionic-framework, active-directory, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, capacitor

I am using Cognito with Azure AD Open ID for SSO. 
Implemented the Login flow using `Auth.federatedSignIn()`. 
I am successfully able to sign in my browser. 
But in mobile, after login, it redirects to my app (i have configured deep links) but my `Auth.currentUser()` is undefined. so that not able to get user data. It seems, the local storage is working fine.
The Amplify is not setting any data in local storage after login in Android.

This is the login Part.

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Azure'})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Login button clicked");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`Error while logging: ${err}`);
    });
```

The below is undefined.

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
```

Works perfectly on browser, but not in ionic capacitor android platform.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?